# How can I write RapidXML content to file in MFC?

Tags: c++, xml, mfc

how can I save the content from RapidXML to xml file?  my app is MFC and I use CString alot because it's easier to manipulate the string.  So if I have code below, how can I save to xml file?

```
#include "rapidxml.hpp"
rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;
rapidxml::xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_type::node_declaration, 0,0,0,0);
decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("xml version", "1.0"));
doc.append_node(decl);  

rapidxml::xml_node<>* comment = doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_type::node_comment, 0, "Application Config");
doc.append_node(comment);

rapidxml::xml_node<>* subsytem = doc.allocate_node(rapidxml::node_type::node_element, "Subsystem");
subsytem->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Name", "My App"));
subsytem->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("Version", "1.0"));
doc.append_node(subsytem);
```

thanks.

Comment: Section 2.4 Printing XML of the RapidXML manual (http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#namespacerapidxml_1printing) present very clearly a number of solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
using namespace rapidxml;
int testmain()
{
    xml_document<> doc;
    xml_node<>* decl = doc.allocate_node(node_declaration);
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("version", "1.0"));
    decl->append_attribute(doc.allocate_attribute("encoding", "UTF-8"));
    doc.append_node(decl);  



    xml_node<> *files = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Files");
    doc.append_node(files);
    xml_attribute<> *attr = doc.allocate_attribute("dummy", "google.com");
    files->append_attribute(attr);

    for(int i = 0;i<10;++i)
    {
        xml_node<> *file = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "File");
        files->append_node(file);

        xml_node<> *path = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Path","File_path");
        file->append_node(path);
        xml_node<> *name = doc.allocate_node(node_element, "Name""File_name");
        file->append_node(name);
    }

    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("c:/example.xml");
    myfile << doc;
    //print(std::cout, doc, 0);
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Make sure to #include "rapidxml_print.hpp" for `myfile << doc` to compile.